# Strange Situation When Try To Retrieve Github Gist Using wp_remote_get

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-remote-get

I have fall in a strange situation. Take a look at below code:

```
<?php
  $args = array( 
    'headers' => array( 
      'Accept' => 'application/vnd.github.v3+json', 
      'Authorization' => 'token 05b2d30a01f60cf09b7af08be8f322b4fd7d831f' 
    ) 
  ); 

  $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://gist.github.com/kampas/63abfe8435d461d30099', $args ); 
  print_r($response); 
?>
```

This code show:

```
[response] => Array ( [code] => 406 [message] => Not Acceptable
```

But when I remove the `$args`, the code prints the whole github gist page in my wordpress post. But I want to print only the gist(code). I use accurate token. My question is:

1. Why `$args` (Authorization headers) doesn't work?
2. How can I get only codeblock from the gist(and not the whole github page)?

I try to use `json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );` but no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with WordPress. It looks like a problem with the parameters you are sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the auth to get gists? [Get a single gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist) using the [Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/).

```
$api_url = 'https://api.github.com/gists/';
$id = '63abfe8435d461d30099';

$response = wp_remote_get($api_url . $id);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$data = json_decode($body, true);

$output = array();
foreach($data[ 'files' ] as $file => $fileInfo) {
    $fR = wp_remote_get($fileInfo[ 'raw_url' ]);
    $fB = wp_remote_retrieve_body($fR);
    $output[] = $fB;
}

echo implode("\n\r", $output);
```

---

**REQUEST**

```
GET /gists/:id
```

---

**RESPONSE**

```
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d",
  "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d/forks",
  "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d/commits",
  "id": "aa5a315d61ae9438b18d",
  "description": "description of gist",
  "public": true,
  "owner": {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "user": null,
  "files": {
    "ring.erl": {
      "size": 932,
      "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/raw/365370/8c4d2d43d178df44f4c03a7f2ac0ff512853564e/ring.erl",
      "type": "text/plain",
      "language": "Erlang",
      "truncated": false,
      "content": "contents of gist"
    }
  },
  "truncated": false,
  "comments": 0,
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d/comments/",
  "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d",
  "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d.git",
  "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d.git",
  "created_at": "2010-04-14T02:15:15Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-06-20T11:34:15Z",
  "forks": [
    {
      "user": {
        "login": "octocat",
        "id": 1,
        "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/dee9c42e4998ce2ea439",
      "id": "dee9c42e4998ce2ea439",
      "created_at": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z",
      "updated_at": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
    }
  ],
  "history": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/aa5a315d61ae9438b18d/57a7f021a713b1c5a6a199b54cc514735d2d462f",
      "version": "57a7f021a713b1c5a6a199b54cc514735d2d462f",
      "user": {
        "login": "octocat",
        "id": 1,
        "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "change_status": {
        "deletions": 0,
        "additions": 180,
        "total": 180
      },
      "committed_at": "2010-04-14T02:15:15Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! But can you give me an idea on how can I stylize the gist code as same as it is on github? (One additional question: why use 'https://api.github.com/gists/' instead of 'https://gist.github.com/kampas/63abfe8435d461d30099' ?

Comment: If you see the data returned from the api it gives you a ton of information about the gist (including all the pages). As for styling, that's better for another question, one where you should post the $output. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Because if you just want to embed the gist then check existing plugins - https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=gist

Comment: http://manovotny.github.io/wp-gist/ adds support for GitHib Gist embeds in WordPress

Comment: Sorry, I am not so familiar with HTTP or RESTful API. How can I run "GET /gists/:id" command in my browser?

Comment: GET means url, /gist/ is after the main API url, :id means add you ID to the constructed url. Essentially I was showing that the solution I provided was documented in the Gist API docs and similar methods exist if you want more features.